# Is there a way to dynamically enter the values for SQL query without value placeholders

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

Suppose I have the sqlite3 query in Python:

```
SELECT COUNT(customerid) FROM customerDetails WHERE age BETWEEN 17 AND 24
```

Is there a method of dynamically entering the age placeholders via user input.

Can this be done via sql variables? It would go along something like this?..

```
SELECT COUNT(customerid) FROM customerDetails WHERE age BETWEEN = ? AND = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just use parametrized queries and pass the values of the placeholder `?`s as a tuple to the `execute` method:

```
min = 10
max = 50
sql = "SELECT COUNT(customerid) FROM customerDetails WHERE age BETWEEN = ? AND = ?"
cursor.execute(sql, (min, max))
```